# Django admin returns 404 on POST, 200 on GET

Tags: python, django

On production server, when I try to edit/create an object then saving fails, returning 404. This only occurs for POST requests, GET requests (loading the page) work fine.
Django is deployed via cPanel and WSGI, DEBUG is False (though it does not work even when it's set to True)

I have deployed the Django app with cpanel, running in a virtualenv. This only seems to happen for a model that uses `FileField` for file upload, other models can be changed/created just fine.

The model:

```py
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    name, ext = filename.split('.')
    return f'images/{instance.advert_id}/{name}.{ext}'

class AdvertImage(models.Model):
    advert = models.ForeignKey(Advert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

URL conf:

```py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
              ] + i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),

    # ... other views....

    prefix_default_language=False
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Navigate to `domain.com/admin/colli/advertimage/1/change/` - the page loads correctly. Fill the form, click save.

The model should be saved and no 404 should occur.
Other models, that do not use `FileField`, for them all admin views work correctly

With DEBUG=True, the full error message is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://example.com/admin/colli/advertimage/1/change/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.change_view
Using the URLconf defined in Colli.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

i18n/
admin/
[name='home']
advert/<slug:slug> [name='detail']
tagauks [name='admin_list']
tagauks/lisa [name='insert']
tagauks/muuda/<int:pk> [name='edit']
tagauks/kasutaja/<int:pk> [name='user_edit']
tagauks/save_image [name='save_image']
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
api/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, colli/advertimage/1/change/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

The view causing this seems to be `change_view`

Comment: The POST does *not* contains a `admin/`, so indeed, it does not find the path.

Comment: You are correct, I did not notice this before. Although, then the question is why? I have not modified urls in admin site, GET request seems to work correctly and the issue only occurs with the model with FileField.

Comment: Is that the full output of the 404 message? I ask because I have seen this recently where the view that caused the 404 was the admin `add_view`

Comment: Added the full error message to the question @IainShelvington

Comment: This also happens with `add_view`, if it's any help

Comment: Have you set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings?

Comment: Yes, production settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/full/path/to/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/full/path/to/static/'

```
Staticfiles are serving correctly, DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE has not been changed

Comment: Any solution of above question ? It also happening with me at namecheap shared hosting. Thanks.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue (with Namecheap). It works absolutely fine locally but when deployed any forms with ImageFields 404 on `POST`. The path definitely exists and works fine for `GET` requests. I've added a bounty to hopefully bring some attention.

Comment: probably you should contact namecheap support. Because if the GET works and POST does not, then it might be an issue with proxy server. Do you have any other view which accepts post request(apart from admin site), can you test them and see if it is behaving the same?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `path('admin/', admin_site.urls)` outside of the `i18n_patterns`? Wondering if django thinks "admin" is a language prefix.

Comment: @ruddra I contacted them and they were unable to help, except for suggesting to upgrade to VPS hosting to allow for server configuration.

Comment: @Ben Good thought but my setup is like you suggested and the problem remains. I've only been able to devise a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950675/6619548

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated middleware ([Internationalization: in URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n))?

```py
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
...
]
```

Comment: I've not. Thanks for sharing something I've not considered, but I'm not sure how this would make a difference. The URLs shouldn't need to be translated in any way. How do you think it might help?

Comment: I added the middleware but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Bounty was auto awarded -- not because the answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never got to the bottom of this, but I have developed a workaround that allows the forms to function.

1. Edit `_get_response(self, request)` in `django.core.handlers.base`. Change `resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)` to `resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path)`.
2. Add this middleware (adjust to your exact needs):

   ```
    class ImageField404Middleware:
        def __init__(self, get_response):
            self.get_response = get_response

        def __call__(self, request):
            response = self.get_response(request)

            if (request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_superuser and response.status_code == 302
                    and request.get_full_path().startswith('/pathtoadmin/')):
                post_messages = get_messages(request)
                for message in post_messages:
                    if ('was added successfully' in message.message or 'was changed successfully' in message.message
                            and message.level == message_levels.SUCCESS):
                        messages.success(request, message.message)
                        redirect_url = request.get_full_path()
                        if '_addanother' in request.POST:
                            redirect_url = re.sub(r'[^/]*/[^/]*/$', 'add/', redirect_url)
                        elif '_save' in request.POST:
                            redirect_url = re.sub(r'[^/]*/[^/]*/(\?.*)?$', '', redirect_url) 
                            if '_changelist_filters' in request.GET:
                                preserved_filters = parse.parse_qsl(request.GET['_changelist_filters'])
                                redirect_url += '?' + parse.urlencode(preserved_filters)         
                        elif '_continue' in request.POST:
                            redirect_url_search = re.search(r'((?<=href=)[^>]*)', message.message)    
                            if redirect_url_search:                                                  
                                redirect_url = redirect_url_search.group(0)                                                  
                                redirect_url = re.sub(r'[\\"]*', '', redirect_url).replace('/pathtoadmin/pathtoadmin/', '/pathtoadmin/')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

            return response
   ```

Not ideal by any means, but works for me at the moment.

I believe these problems may, in part at least, be caused by ModSecurity Apache. Some problems I had went away after the hosting provider later reconfigured this.

You can read more details here: https://medium.com/@mnydigital/how-to-resolve-django-admin-404-post-error-966ce0dcd39d

Comment: Please can you specify on which file the Image404Middleware should be placed in and also how to set the path to admin...