# django on cpanel returnt 404 uploading file

Tags: django, cpanel

i am having a problem uploading files to my server (shareserver) in cpanel.

when I upload a file either by admin or by a view it responds 404

if someone has help I would be very grateful

> settings

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT  =   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', ...
```

> urls

```
...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, show_indexes= True
) + static(
    settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
)
```

> model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    produc_pic = models.ImageField(default = '',null=True, blank=True)
```

> .htaccess

```
<IfModule Litespeed>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/ferre/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/ferre>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/media/
Alias /static/ /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/static/

<Directory /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ibhfrwld/ferre-bianconeri/ferreteria-bianconeri/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

[*************** directory tree ****************](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOzp4.png)

Comment: There is a bountied similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344774/django-admin-returns-404-on-post-200-on-get Unfortunately no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution here,
https://smartlazycoding.com/django-tutorial/deploy-a-django-website-to-a2-hosting
I encounter the same issue. It was causes by passenger_wsgy.py. Initially I was only used

from mysite.wsgi import application

it won't work, so I uses the code below, It work fine for me

```
import os
import sys
# Set up paths and environment variables
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and 
        len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

Comment: do not apply exactly this solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796728/django-admin-404-error-when-creating-or-editing-a-model-instance nor the one you suggest but if I talk to him support team and I asked them to deactivate the "modsec" that was previously available in cpanel, they ask you why and you tell them that due to the incompatibility with django and voila, if you need to activate it again, you contact them again.

after this everything worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

do not apply exactly this solution in this thread [Django admin 404 error when creating or editing a model instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796728/django-admin-404-error-when-creating-or-editing-a-model-instance) nor the one you suggest but if I talk to him support team and I asked them to deactivate the "modsec" that was previously available in cpanel, they ask you why and you tell them that due to the incompatibility with django and voila, if you need to activate it again, you contact them again.

after this everything worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

I got the above error after changing from my_project.wsgi import application
To yours I still get the same error.