# Django admin 404 error when creating or editing a model instance

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector-python

I'm currently debugging a weird problem with a Django site where one specific model is triggering a 404 error when creating a new instance or editing an existing one in the admin interface.

Specifically, the error occurs when the form is submitted. I can `GET` the changeform just fine.

This is only occuring on the live site and only when saving this model. All other models behave as expected, and when I run it locally, everything works as expected. When created programatically, everything is also fine both live and locally.

Here's my model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    """Base Content class."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(max_length=30000, blank=True, null=True, config_name='admin')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ContentPage(Content):
    """Represents a page of generic text content."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    has_url = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Sets the page to accessible via a URL.')
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='myfiles/banners/', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Create the slug from the title."""
        self.slug = slugify(self.title[:100])
        super(ContentPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `ContentPage` class is the one triggering the problem in the admin interface. My other class that inherits from `Content` works fine.

I have stripped back my admin setup to the following and it is still occuring:

```
class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        """Define custom admin URLs."""
        urls = super(CustomAdminSite, self).get_urls()

        # Append some new views here...

        return urls


admin_site = CustomAdminSite()
admin_site.register(ContentPage)
```

Here's a basic URL config that reproduces the problem:

```
from myapp.admin import admin_site


urlpatterns = [
    path('mycooladminsite/', admin_site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

A few other things I've checked:

- I have no signals interferring with the save.
- I am not performing any actions in the model's `save()` method.
- I have checked for `get_object_or_404()` calls and can't see any that would affect this.

I've spent a few hours digging through this and I'm currently at a brick wall.

The database engine is `mysql.connector.django`, with Django version 2.2.11. I can't change the engine or update Django to 3.x yet for this site.

This is a recent problem that I did not notice previously.

Update:

I've narrowed down the problem to the ImageField. When I remove that from the fields displayed, the problem does not occur on save.

I'm using a custom admin form but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I've tried using the default and it still occurs. I've been looking for exceptions in the storage class but haven't found any. I stripped it all the way back and the error remains.

I've examined the local 302 `POST` and production 404 `POST` in Firefox Developer Tools and they're virtually identical but production server is Apache and `x-powered-by` is Phusion Passenger, whereas locally the server is WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3.

I've actually noticed a 404 occurring with other `multipart/form-data` forms in production now, which I never got before.

Comment: I have since found a similar question but cannot mark as duplicate as there is no accepted answer. I have added a bounty to the question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344774/django-admin-returns-404-on-post-200-on-get Other info here: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-contrib-admin-options-add-view-404-with-image-field/3246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never fully got to the bottom of what was going on, but I did devise a workaround to at least allow the forms to function correctly, as I discussed in [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950675/6619548):

> 1. Edit `_get_response(self, request)` in `django.core.handlers.base`. Change `resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)` to
>    `resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path)`.
> 2. Add this middleware (adjust to your exact needs):
>
>    ```
>     class ImageField404Middleware:
>         def __init__(self, get_response):
>             self.get_response = get_response
>
>         def __call__(self, request):
>             response = self.get_response(request)
>
>             if (request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_superuser and response.status_code == 302
>                     and request.get_full_path().startswith('/pathtoadmin/')):
>                 post_messages = get_messages(request)
>                 for message in post_messages:
>                     if ('was added successfully' in message.message or 'was changed successfully' in message.message
>                             and message.level == message_levels.SUCCESS):
>                         messages.success(request, message.message)
>                         redirect_url = request.get_full_path()
>                         if '_addanother' in request.POST:
>                             redirect_url = re.sub(r'[^/]*/[^/]*/$', 'add/', redirect_url)
>                         elif '_save' in request.POST:
>                             redirect_url = re.sub(r'[^/]*/[^/]*/(\?.*)?$', '', redirect_url) 
>                             if '_changelist_filters' in request.GET:
>                                 preserved_filters = parse.parse_qsl(request.GET['_changelist_filters'])
>                                 redirect_url += '?' + parse.urlencode(preserved_filters)   
>                         elif '_continue' in request.POST:
>                             redirect_url_search = re.search(r'((?<=href=)[^>]*)', message.message)    
>                             if redirect_url_search:                                                  
>                                 redirect_url = redirect_url_search.group(0)                                                  
>                                 redirect_url = re.sub(r'[\\"]*', '', redirect_url).replace('/pathtoadmin/pathtoadmin/', '/pathtoadmin/')
>                         return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
>
>             return response
>    ```
>
> Not ideal by any means, but works for me at the moment.
>
> You can read more details here:
> https://medium.com/@mnydigital/how-to-resolve-django-admin-404-post-error-966ce0dcd39d

I believe these problems may, in part at least, be caused by ModSecurity Apache. Some problems I had went away after the hosting provider later reconfigured this.

Comment: You can use [monkey patching](https://filippo.io/instance-monkey-patching-in-python/) to install this fix and be future upgrade safe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the issue is but if you don't have logs, run it on prod with DEBUG=False, don't use Sentry etc. and it happens only when you save `ContentPage` admin form, then you can overwrite `save_new` or `save_model` method in your `ModelAdmin` with

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:
            obj.save()
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("blah")
```

(or `save_new` accordingly)

and check logs.

Or just use Sentry. They have a free tier

Comment: I just tried this but no exception occurred in `save_model`. I did log the exception in my `handler404` view and it's saying a matching path can't be found... but I don't know why. It can load the page fine on a `GET` request and the path is of course identical.

Comment: You say it happens on form save. Try overwrite `save_new` then.

Comment: Will try tomorrow. The issue is potentially occurring before the object is saved -- it seems like the ImageField/storage class is maybe complaining about something but not sure at this stage. Will take a further look.

Comment: Where should I overwrite `save_new`? I'm only aware of this as a `ModelFormSet` function. Also, the problem occurs when editing an existing instance, not just when creating a new one. I've narrowed the problem down to the ImageField and added some more info to the question.

Comment: Yep, then I think it doesn't apply to your case. AFAIK it's only there. Then maybe `save` method on the model?

Comment: No exception raised in model `save` method. Only place I can get any exception details is my `handler404` function but it doesn't show me where in the code it came from. It just tells me the current URL is a 404 which it's not because I press enter in the address bar and it loads fine. I think some other URL in the background might be 404-ing...